# Single-Thread asynchronous processing in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have a question about Java threading. Is possible run two tasks asynchronously when I use only Main Thread? I read this article: [Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)
Second answer says that is possible case where is only one thread (not main thread and one other) and tasks are executed asynchronously. I think that it is not possible in Java because exists only one flow of control.
I think that in Java each task need own thread for execution tasks asynchronously.

Comment: In C# or Node.js, yes, absolutely - those at least have that feature as part of the language. I truthfully don't remember if Java has this feature yet, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous processing with a single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263574/asynchronous-processing-with-a-single-thread)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: yes. This is actually a common feature of non-blocking I/O. Java has a non-blocking I/O library - you can see more details about it [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html). (I'm truthfully not aware of all of the implementation details of the library, though, so I'm not sure if there's a guarantee that it won't create extra threads). This is a notable feature of Node.js, for example, and the .NET Framework has this feature available as well.

Here's an analogy to illustrate the difference between single-threaded asynchronous programming and multithreading: suppose that you go to a restaurant with a group of 10 people. When the waiter asks the first person to order, he's not ready yet. In "ordinary" single-threaded programming with blocking I/O, the waiter waits until he's ready before moving on to anyone else. In multithreading, you could bring in a second waiter to wait for him (or to take the other group members' orders). You could also bring in several waiters who each take the order of, for example, 2 or 3 group members. In asynchronous/non-blocking I/O, you simply move on to the next person in the group and come back to the first guy when he's ready.

Obviously, I'm glossing over a lot of the subtleties here, but hopefully that illustrates the difference to some degree.

For more information, see:

[Does an asynchronous call always create/call a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598436/does-an-asynchronous-call-always-create-call-a-new-thread)

[Asynchronous processing with a single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263574/asynchronous-processing-with-a-single-thread)

[There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) (focuses on C#)