# "Undefined" as a result of the assignment

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I'm a new in javascript. Faced with the following problem

```
var list = [];

initList(); // after this function I have some elements in `list`

var node = list[0]; //after the assignment firebug says `node` is undefined. `list[0]` is defined and contains object like {a:"value",b:"value1", ...}
```

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried to declarate `node` like `var node = {};`. But It doesn't work too.

Here my initList function. Hopefully there will be those who will want to grasp it :))

```
function initList() {

    d3.json("./config.json", function (error, txt) {
        if (error) {
            console.debug(error)
        }
        txt.forEach(function (bop, i) {

            var nd = {};

            d3.json("./cgi-bin/getshmid.sh?key=" + (195951310 + bop.bop_id), function (error, shm) {
                if (error) {
                    console.debug(error)
                } else {
                    console.debug(bop, i)
                }


                d3.select("#tplace")
                    .append("h3")
                    .text("BOP's ID = " + bop.bop_id)

                var table = d3.select("#tplace")
                    .append("table")
                    .attr("id", "shmid_" + shm.id);

                var thead = table.append("tr")

                thead.append("td")
                    .text("Блоки детектирования, ID")
                thead.append("td")
                    .text("Текущее значение")
                thead.append("td")
                    .text("Предупредительная уставка")
                thead.append("td")
                    .text("Аварийная уставка")
                thead.append("td")
                    .text("Статус")
                thead.append("td")
                    .text("Превышение ПУ")
                thead.append("td")
                    .text("Превышение АУ")

                bop.BDs.forEach(function (bd, i) {
                    var tbody = table.append("tr")
                        .attr("class", "bd")
                    tbody.append("td")
                        .text(bd.index + 1)
                    tbody.append("td")
                        .attr("id", "val")
                    tbody.append("td")
                        .attr("id", "pz")
                        .attr("class", "edit " + (516 + i * 16) + "")
                    tbody.append("td")
                        .attr("id", "az")
                        .attr("class", "edit " + (518 + i * 16) + "")
                    tbody.append("td")
                        .attr("id", "status")
                    tbody.append("td")
                        .attr("id", "state_pz")
                    tbody.append("td")
                        .attr("id", "state_az")
                })

                nd = foo(shm.id);
                list.push(nd);
            })
        })
    })
};

function foo(id) {

    var node = {
        value: id,
        table: d3.select('#shmid_' + id),
        tr: d3.select('#shmid_' + id).selectAll(".bd"),
        bds: []
    };

    node.tr.each(function (d, i) {

        var bd = {};

        d3.select(this).selectAll("td").each(function (d, i) {

            switch (d3.select(this).attr("id")) {
                case 'val':
                    bd.val = d3.select(this);
                case 'pz':
                    bd.pz = d3.select(this);
                case 'az':
                    bd.az = d3.select(this);
                case 'status':
                    bd.status = d3.select(this);
                case 'state_pz':
                    bd.stpz = d3.select(this);
                case 'state_az':
                    bd.staz = d3.select(this);
            }
        });

        node.bds.push(bd);
    });

    return node;
};
```

Comment: Do you do `var list = ...` in your function ?

Comment: Can you show the `initList` function?

Comment: Based on the example you specified your result of node cannot be undefined.

Comment: Please keep it simple: after `initList()`, `console.log(list)`. Don't subject us to screens and screens full of code we can't run.

Comment: @deceze So i said, that after `initList()` list's elements contains objects. So list[0] =  {a:"value", b:"value", ...etc}

Comment: How have you tested this exactly? Doesn't look like you've used a `console.log` after `initList`. We need to know how you arrived at your conclusions, not just take your word for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the question, the problem is that `initList` is an asynchronous function. So the array `list` won't be initialized.

```
var list = [];
initList(); //WARNING: asynchronous function!!!
var node = list[0];
```

You should start learning about [`JavaScript Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise#Constructor)

---

This is what happens with your code. The first line creates an array named `list`. The second line initializes the list via ajax calls. But before the callback happens, the third line gets executed giving you an error cos you are trying to fetch the first element of an un-populated array.

---

Update:

I have not tried this yet, but [d3.promise plugin](https://github.com/kristw/d3.promise) looks simple.

```
var promise = d3.promise.json('test.json')
promise.then(function (data) {
    // call successful
}, function (error) {
    //call failed
});
```

Comment: @ИосифСталин Not a separate thread, but *asynchronously*. It finishes sometime *after* you try to access the list.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, you might wanna read this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/598436/17447

Comment: @naveen @deceze Thanks for topics! But can I solve this problem in an easier way than `Promises`?

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding i have added the below code.

```js
function initList(){
 list.push(1);
 list.push(2);
}

var list = [];

initList(); // after this function I have some elements in `list`

var node = list[0]; //after the assignment firebug says `node` is undefined. `list[0]` is defined and contains object like {a:"value",b:"value1", ...}
console.log(node);
```

`node` has the value 1 now. I hope this helps you.

And also please check the scope the variable `list` in you code.